# MAUI Text To Speech Aloud

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, text-to-speech, speakerphone

I am using .NET MAUI, and calling the TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync method.  It works fine when I listen into the the Samsung Android phone I have connected.

But what I want is the audio to be outputted through the speaker phone - aloud and not having to put the phone to my ear.  There is an app I downloaded, the Android Accessibility Suite, which allows text on a web page (for example) to be read aloud and it works fine.  I want the same thing (aloud/speaker phone) when I call TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync in my .NET MAUI program.  How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Tried TextToSpeech.SpeakAsync

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+api+enable+speaker+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: You can try to use the  [SpeechOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.media.speechoptions?view=net-maui-8.0) class to achieve this.  For more information, please check [Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/text-to-speech?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#settings).